# List of <Checkbox> components from Enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I am new to React.

I want to build a list of checkbox, from an enumeration, taking the value of the elements of the enumeration.

I found other examples but never equals to what I am trying to reach.

I have declared this **enum**.

```
declare enum options_analysis {
    Analysis_1 = "Analysis 1",
    Analysis_2 = "Analysis 2",
    Analysis_3 = "Analysis 3",
  }
```

Then, in a file index.tsx:

```
    <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>
          Chose the Analysis:
        </FormLabel>
        
        <Checkbox aria-label="Analysis 1">Analysis 1</Checkbox>
```

Here, **instead of this manual**  code, I want a function to build the Checkbox from the values string of the enumeration.

How is it possible ?
I was trying to use ***?.map(***

```
          {
            options_analysis?.map(({ option }: options_analysis) => {
              return (
                <Checkbox aria-label= {options_analysis}>                   
                   {options_analysis}
                </Checkbox>
              )
            })}
```

but this code obviously doesn't work.

If there are other details missed, please, let me know, this is all new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to obtain an array of the enum values and then loop through them. This allows you to iterate through the enum values and generate the checkboxes.

```js
enum OptionsAnalysis {
  Analysis_1 = "Analysis 1",
  Analysis_2 = "Analysis 2",
  Analysis_3 = "Analysis 3",
}

{
  Object.values(OptionsAnalysis).map((option, index) => (
    <Checkbox key={index} aria-label={option}>
      {option}
    </Checkbox>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks ikonuk, it was an easy one, I suppose : )
would you mind to make me a vote up ? I am going anyway to approve your answer ! Thank you !